# Set responsive div height to equal its sibling

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two divs whose widths are controlled by percentages. I want the right div to be exactly as tall as the left div, which expands and shrinks based on the width of the image it contains and the width of the browser window.

Is there a way to accomplish this without javascript?

http://jsfiddle.net/5JU2t/

Comment: only other way I know of but no use really if you don't need a fixed height container http://jsfiddle.net/p3WjC/ I personally would not use this - another solution I use is css if your wanting to get the right column to always have its bg image showing the full length of the page?

Comment: The old school [faux columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/) handles this sort of thing nicely.

Comment: that's what I meant ye with the css! best solution I think

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this is to make the `.right` div absolutely positioned and setting `top` and `bottom` to `0`.

Just remember to position the parent (`.main`) div relatively and remove all of the floats:

```
.right {
    bottom:0;
    position: absolute;
    right:0; 
    top: 0;
}

.main {
    position: relative;
}
```

**Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/5JU2t/1/**

#### Note

The reason the right column is a little longer in the example is due to the white space added under an image. Should you only be using an image in this column then you can add `float: left` to the image to resolve this:

**Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/5JU2t/2/**

Comment: ye already posted that to him in the jsfiddle url above - only thing I can think of too without using JS

Comment: this did the trick, thanks. I do have other items in the column with the image, but adding `line-height: 0;` seems to get rid of the whitespace. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I'd try wrapping it in a third div and give your two divs either `height:auto` or `height: 100%`.

Comment: doesn't work - he has already tried height:100%; on the right column - I wouldn't have thought another div with it would either

Answer (score 0):

Set the parent (`.main`) to display as table
and set the children (`.right`, `.left`) to display as table cell.

Answer (score -6):

I would say funk all the extra css and use a table layout

Comment: Tables should only be used for tabular data, imo.

Comment: display:table-cell would be better by the way, that is fancy and kind of table :)